# how to capture ip camera with C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ip-camera

This below is the code that I have trying to capture the Wanscam ip camera however does not work now is raising some exceptions and does at all and I really do not know whats going on

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
sometimes this is the exception but many times does not even know what kind exception happened.

Please anyone can spot something, since now thank you all.

there is just a button in the form, and as long this button display Stop the loop will go around updating the picture box.

and the camera is a Wanscam AJ-C2WA-C198
I know this is not the greatest camera in the world.

and my admin name and my password are match right.

EDIT::
I notice that on VLC I see that image after I enter the admin and password again but I already did on the URL that is weird

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace cam01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public Thread _cameraThread;
        private string metaUrl = "http://home-ip-camera.dyndns-server.com/videostream.asf?user=<USER_NAME>&pwd=<PASSWORD>resolution=64&rate=0";

        public HttpWebRequest req;

        public WebResponse res;

        public System.IO.Stream stream;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnMain.Text.Equals("Start"))
            {
                if (_cameraThread == null)
                    _cameraThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));

                _cameraThread.Start();
                btnMain.Text = "Stop";
            }
            else
            {
                btnMain.Text = "Start";
                _cameraThread.Abort();
                _cameraThread = null;
            }
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            while (btnMain.Text.Equals("Stop"))
            {
                try
                {

                    req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(metaUrl);

                    req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

                    req.Timeout = 20000;

                    res = req.GetResponse();

                    stream = res.GetResponseStream();

                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

                    res.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check, that http port are setted correct. (Route on your DDNS or specify in get-query). By default port is 99, not 80!

Also, you can try to use `/videostream.cgi?user=<USENAME>&pwd=<PASSWORD>` - it get you MJPEG stream instead FFMPEG, provided by `videostream.asf`

Finally, try to specify creditals in your request:

```
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<USENAME>", "<PASSWORD>");
```

and try another query params: `loginuse=<USENAME>&loginpass=<PASSWORD>`

Answer (score 0):

Try find the sdk(software development kit) of the camera either in CD or on the company website.Mostly, Cameras SDKs are written in c/c++ for performance reasons.Try to wrapper them in C#.
Pointers are strongly discouraged in c# but has included just for the reason of Microsoft Backward compatibility for unmanaged codes.